# error when using Compare-Object in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a diff of two files using Compare-Object cmdlet and print the ones missing in the second file (slave.txt) when compared to the first file (master.txt). In this example, I wanted to print user1, user3 which are in master.txt but not present in slave.txt. I have a pre-requisite of storing each values in the file as a variable, so "mobj" and "sobj" cannot be ignored.

I am finding this error when running the script. what could be the issue here?

```
~]# cat master.txt
user1
user2
user3

~]# cat slave.txt
user2
user4
```

Code:

```
$mfile = Get-Content "C:\master.txt"
$sfile = Get-Content "C:\slave.txt" 
foreach ($mobj in $mfile) {

foreach($sobj in $sfile){
        Compare-Object (ls $mobj) (ls $sobj) -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTime -passthru | Where { $_.PSParentPath -eq (gi $mobj).PSPath } 

    }
}
```

The error reported is:

```
Compare-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ReferenceObject' because it is null.
```

Comment: Why are you trying to compare the output of `ls` (which is an alias for `Get-ChildItem`)?

Comment: Please go back to the question you got the `Compare-Object` line from and carefully review **all** answers to that question.

Answer (score 1):

Er, not what your last question meant.  Just because that question was marked as a duplicate doesn't mean that's the *exact unmodified code* you have to use.

Try this:

```
$mfile = Get-Content "C:\master.txt"
$sfile = Get-Content "C:\slave.txt" 

#In master.txt not in slave.txt
Compare-Object $mfile $sfile | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject

#In slave.txt not in master.txt
Compare-Object $mfile $sfile | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
```

Answer (score 0):

Either start running your code from the directory where the user's folders are, or you need to edit your master and slave files.

You're runnig `LS/Dir` and without executing in the source directory where the user's profiles are found, or explicitly specifying the full path to their profiles in the source file, you're going to have this error, because LS will throw a non-terminating error(which is interpreted as a null, as no data or objects go to stdout/the pipeline) if it can't find a directory.